# Let a, b, c, d be rational numbers...

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $a, b, c, d$ be rational numbers, where $\sqrt{b}$ and $\sqrt{d}$ exist and are irrational. If $a + \sqrt{b} = c + \sqrt{d}$, prove that $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Answer (score 4):

Set $t=a-c$. Then you have $t+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{d}$. Therefore
$$
t^2+2t\sqrt{b}+b=d.
$$
If $t\ne 0$, this means…

Comment: Could you possibly explain further where you're going with this? I've been working at it with your hint and still can't come to a conclusion

Comment: Nevermind, got it! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Paige For the record: if $t\ne0$, then from $2t\sqrt{b}=d-b-t^2$ you get $\sqrt{b}$ is rational, which it isn't. So $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\ 0\ne  \alpha = \sqrt b\! -\!\sqrt d\in\Bbb Q\,\Rightarrow\ \alpha' = \sqrt b\!+\!\sqrt d = \dfrac{\ b-d}{\sqrt b \!-\! \sqrt d}\in\Bbb Q\,\Rightarrow\,\alpha\!+\!\alpha' = 2\sqrt b\in \Bbb Q\,\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$